I Can't Run Application Command with Discord.js v14
I'm just trying to learn how to bot with Discord.js v14. Even though the Slash Commands I saved in my bot are saving and working properly, when I try this for the Application Command, it saves the commands, but when I start the interaction, "The application could not respond." Even though I added some code to catch errors while doing this, I can't catch any errors, so I don't know what I need to fix.
I use @discordjs/builders for such command actions.
An example command that does not work but registers on the servers as a Application Command:
const { ContextMenuCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
        .setName('Hello')
        .setType(2),

    async run(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'hi!', ephemeral: true });
    },
};

The result I expect from the command is that the application responds successfully and implements the function of the code, as in Slash Commands.
My bot's interactionCreate.js file:
const client = require('../../index.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../config.json");

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.slash_commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return interaction.reply({ content: "invalid command", ephemeral: true });

    try {
        await command.run(client, interaction);
    } catch (e) {

        function id(length) {
            var result = '';
            var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            var charactersLength = characters.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
                    charactersLength));
            }
            return result;
        }

        const i = id(12);

        console.error(`Error ID: ${i}\n ` + e);

        await interaction.reply({ content: `Error ID: \`${i}\``, ephemeral: true });
    }
});


Where do you call that run method?

@ZsoltMeszaros In my interactionCreate.js file sir, I added the file to my question above

My problem still persists...
